ROS2 Moveit - motion planning problem with collisions
I'm facing an issue with simple motion planning using custom C++ node (https://github.com/oto313/ros_test/blob/main/src/aiva_executor/src/aiva_executor.cpp) on a custom robot (Dobot Nova 2). I've created a simple scene in ROS  and executed a movement to the left side of a barrier, which works fine. However, when I attempt to plan a movement to the other side of the barrier, the planning fails with:
MoveGroupInterface::plan() failed or timeout reached

I've tried increasing the PlanningTime, NumPlanningAttempts, and switched to different planners, but nothing seems to help. Sometimes it generates a plan that goes through the collision object, while other times it creates an odd plan with thousands of steps that completely ignores the collision objects. Then I also tried to decreased longest_valid_segment_fraction to 0.001. But it does not help either
I've set up a repository for testing at https://github.com/oto313/ros_test. It includes the aiva_executor package aiva_executor and the nova_moveit package (MoveIt configuration). The aiva_executor package contains a simple C++ project that executes the motion plan. You can use the pos parameter to specify one of two positions for the robot to move to. nova2_moveit contains robot definition and launch files. I have created custom launch file because the generated one does not work for me (https://github.com/oto313/ros_test/blob/main/src/DOBOT_6Axis_ROS2_V3/nova2_moveit/launch/run.launch.py). Please refer to the README.md for instructions on running the project.
Could you help me pinpoint the issue?
Thanks
ROS2 version: jazzy

Silly question, but are you sure a plan exists?

Hi, Thanks for response. Yes I am sure. I can plan movement frop top position to the left or bottom, but from left to right position it sometimes works but ignore collision objects. See videos https://imgur.com/a/gidu7wq. I don't know if there is something wrong with the robot model that is causing it to miscalculate collisions

Here are two videos. In one robot goes to the left and in seconds robots goes to the right. But between these exact points it does not want to travel https://imgur.com/a/rQ4G2dQ

I found the problem. I accidentally entered wrong max and min position in joint_limits.yaml (https://github.com/oto313/ros_test/blob/main/src/DOBOT_6Axis_ROS2_V3/nova2_moveit/config/joint_limits.yaml). It should be in radians but I had it in degrees. Strange behavior when you have wrong units
